# Django REST framework: want to switch API processing depending on conditions

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want to replace all processes of a specific API according to specific conditions (settings or database value).

Example : it usually returns a value from the DB, but returns a fixed value for a specific client.

I thought that it is possible by using middleware, I implemented the following, but it does not work.

error content
"The response content must be rendered before it can be accessed"

I would like to render it, but please tell me how to do it.

```py
# extensions.test_middleware
from extensions.hoge import hogehoge

class SimpleMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        if request.path == '/api/v1/hogehoge/':
            return hogehoge(request)
        response = self.get_response(request)
        return response
```

```py
# extensions.hoge
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.response import Response


def hogehoge(request):
    return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

```py
# settings.py
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'extensions.test_middleware.SimpleMiddleware'
]
```

```
[ERROR] 2020-05-21 12:58:53,658 log 1320 /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/log.py 228 Internal Server Error: /api/v1/hogehoge/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 96, in __call__
    response = self.process_response(request, response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/middleware/common.py", line 112, in process_response
    response['Content-Length'] = str(len(response.content))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 128, in content
    'The response content must be rendered before it can be accessed.'
django.template.response.ContentNotRenderedError: The response content must be rendered before it can be accessed.
[ERROR] 2020-05-21 12:58:53,659 basehttp 1320 /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py 154 "GET /api/v1/hogehoge/ HTTP/1.1" 500 65447
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it is not the best, I got a good implementation, so I will answer it myself.

```py
# extensions.test_middleware
from django.http import JsonResponse
from rest_framework.request import Request

from extensions.hoge import HogeView

class SimpleMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        response = self.get_response(request)
        return response

    def process_view(self, request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs):
        # if view_func.__name__ == 'HogeView': # compare by class name
        if request.path == '/api/v1/hogehoge/': # compare by class url path
            # Django and DRF have different Request
            # convert django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIRequest to rest_framework.request.Request
            req = Request(request)
            res = HogeView.get(HogeView, req)

            # process_view must return django.http.Response
            # DRF's view returns rest_framework.response.Response
            # convert rest_framework.response.Response to django.http.Response
            return JsonResponse(res.data, status=res.status_code)
        else:
            return None
```

```py
# extensions.hoge.HogeView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.views import APIView
class HogeView(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        return Response({'aaa': 'bbb'})
```

```py
# settings.py

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'extensions.test_middleware.SimpleMiddleware'
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a url for hogehoge view and use `redirect` function for this

```
def __call__(self, request):
    if request.path == '/api/v1/hogehoge/':
        return redirect(reverse('hogehoge')) # I suppose you have url named hogehoge
    response = self.get_response(request)
    return response
```

Comment: Thank you for answering!
However, if you publish the URL, you can use the API by directly accessing the URL.
Is it not possible to do only the processing after accessing the URL?